# Group Theory - Natural Coordinate Function

Tags: group-theory, functions

I am studying *Shattered Symmetry - From the Periodic Table to the Eightfold Way*; in order to start getting into group theory, and quantum mechanics.

I am struggling to understand what the author refers to as the *Natural Coordinate Functions*. I think the paragraph the author has written has some serious errors because I have understood the entire book almost perfectly up until this section. The section introducing these functions is below:

---

### **Example 3.2: Natural coordinate functions**

As another example, let us look at a rather special kind of function known as natural coordinate functions. These simply correspond to the coordinate variables *$[x, y]$*. Clearly, these are functions. As an example, the value, which the function x associates with point P, is nothing else than the coordinate number $a_x$ .

Hence,

$x (P) = a_x ;$

$y (P) = a_y$

A convenient way to represent these functions is by means of two osculating spheres, as shown in Figure 3.4. This works as follows. Consider a given point P within a Cartesian reference frame $\sum (x, y)$ with x-coordinate $a_x = a cos φ$ and y-coordinate $a_y = a sin φ$ (Figure 3.4A). This point is represented in Figure 3.4C by the point $P_x$, which is lying on the radius vector to P but at a distance $a_x$ from the origin (see also Figure 3.4A). For a point on the x-axis, $P$ and $P_x$ coincide, because in this case, $a_x = a$.

On the other hand, by increasing the angle of elevation $φ$ from $0$ to $π/2$, keeping the radius $a$ fixed, the $P_x$ points describe a curved line, which ultimately approaches the origin when $P$ reaches the y-axis, and hence $a_x = 0$ (Figure 3.4C).

Similarly, when lowering the angle below the x-axis, we obtain a curve that approaches the origin from below for $φ = −π/2$.

---

Now for my question(s):

> 1. From the author's first introduction of these functions, I would expect the function to simply output a point $P$'s x or y coordinate
>      value. Is this correct?
> 2. Am I correct in thinking that $a_x$ is the x-component of the point P?
> 3. The author says "Consider a point $P$ ..." followed immediately by "This point is represented by $P_x$ in figure 3.4A". This seems conflicting to me
>      since there are two points in figure 3.4A, $P$, and $P_x$.
> 4. Is this following a correct interpretation of the text?: We take some point $P$ in a Cartesian reference frame that can be represented as
>      a vector, similar to the polar representation of a complex number $z = re^{iφ}$. We then vary $φ$ over the interval $[0, \pi/2]$. As we do
>      this, we plot a new vector that has magnitude = $r*cos(φ)$ and
>      angle $φ$. I think this is what the author is trying to get
>      across, but I need some help/confirmation that I'm right in my
>      thinking.

I am not kidding; I have been reading this page over and over for almost 2 days and I just cannot understand what is going on. Any help is appreciated.

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're right about $a_x$ and $a_y$:  they are the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of $P$, respectively. This is precisely what is meant by the coordinate functions, $x(P)=a_x$ and $y(P)=a_y$.

Now, $P_x$ and $Q_y$ are defined a little differently,  as in the picture.  Namely, $P_x$ is $(a_x,0)$ rotated through the angle $\phi$.

Let's look at your concern $3$.  The point $P_x$ is described as the point, determined by $P$, lying on the radius to $P$ at a distance $a_x=a\cos\varphi $ from the origin.   Thus $P_x$ is a point distinct from $P$, and,  the set of all $P_x$ determine a sphere of diameter $a$ (where $a$ is the modulus of $P$).

Comment: Hi, thanks. I think what is confusing about the wording is that a function that takes a point P as a 'vector' and spits out the x-component, in my eyes, is simply $y = rcos(\theta)$. So, as he defines the function, they should really just mimic a cosine, or sine curve. It is like there is another aspect to the functions that he neglects to explain.

Comment: And yes -- $Q$ uses $\theta$, which is varied over the interval $[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$, I think.

Comment: Sure.  Well,  he does have picture $B)$, which is a cosine curve.

Comment: I find no error.   Picture $(C)$ is indeed correct, based on the description and picture $(A)$.  As you said, $(D)$ is analogous.

Comment: The author has indeed described osculating circles:  given by the coordinate functions.  I think the trick is to convince yourself they are really circles.  For, as the author indicates,  the angle of elevation is increased from $0$ to $\dfrac {\pi}2$, but the radius, $\dfrac a2$, is kept fixed.